# How to improve the performance of a query execution with bigger resultset in spring

Tags: java, spring, oracle

I have a native query inside my Java Spring application that hits an oracle DB and fetches a large resultset (close to 20000 records). Current approach is that I used Spring's JdbcTemplate to execute the query, which takes about few minutes to execute the query. What will be the better approach to improve the performance in executing this query?

Comment: Have you checked how much time your query needs to execute directly on the DB using SQL Client (SQLDeveloper, Toad, etc) ? I bet this is not because of Spring, but your query being slow.

Comment: Could you post the sql here? Maybe there are expensive joins used on non-indexed tables or similar stuff

Comment: There is too little information here. Post some code that is actually being used. My guess, the query is quick enough but you are using a `RowMapper` converting each row into an object. That is slow and basically reading all those rows in memory is generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I guess pagination is not an option right?.

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/spring-data-jpa-and-pagination.html

In any case you gonna have a bottleneck since you´re not using BigData tecnologies as NoSQL DB as Mongo or Casandra.

Take a look just in case if it´s possible.

http://www.springio.net/creating-big-data-applications-with-spring-xd/

Answer (score 1):

Find the bottleneck before optimizing. If 90% time is spent materializing results, 9% transferring data over your network and 1% in simple Java operations there is no point to optimize Java.

[Oracle docs chapter "21 Using Application Tracing Tools"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28274/sqltrace.htm#PFGRF010%20Oracle%20docs) explains database server side tracing. This and EXPLAIN statement is a good starting point.